# Woocommerce - product prices depending on delivery method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a restaurant website based on Woocommerce - the client has different prices for his products - one price for delivery, and one price for sitting.

The customer can order products and be delivered and also he can book a table in the restaurant, by ordering the products, and in the checkout section he selects the book a table option.

So - am I able to have 2 prices for a product and then apply one of them depending on the delivery method?

Variations is not a good idea - since I cannot have one product for sitting and one for table booking in the cart.

Comment: The simplest method would be to make "Delivery Method" an [attribute of the product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/).  And attributes CAN change the price of the product.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want the users to be able to select products from delivery and booking - it would mess the entire flow.

Comment: In this case, why not use "Shipping" methods?

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Could you just have two shipping methods: One for "dine in" and one for "delivery"? And the rate(s) for the shipping are different as appropriate?  Also - think of this through the customer's perspective: When I look at a product, what pricing do I see? Do I see two prices? One? Do I select the price at that point? Is it a "Secret" until checkout?

Comment: The idea is that the product price is different - it is not just a matter of adding a tax or a % value from the product price. The ideal case would be to have some dynamic pricing group, display the products based on a filter (the group) and then checkout.

Comment: So could you please modify the question and include the anticipated "flow" and "experience" for the user? It's very unclear to me how you want to see this happen, and why attributes are not *the* solution to the issue.

Comment: I guess you could add a field to the metabox for "delivery" price. And use the default price as the "dine in" price. (Or vice versa). You'd be able to display this additional field in the template somewhere. And then when you set the delivery method (perhaps as a shipping method) you can alter the cart prices.

Answer (score 0):

check below code, it may give you idea about fulfill your requirement.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
    function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {   
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {   
            $productId = $value['data']->id;
            if ( check delivered product) {
            {
                // product to be delivered              
                $value['data']->price = $value['data']->price + $your_custom_price;
            }
            else{
                //book table
                $value['data']->price = $value['data']->price;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```